# Haskell Glut: Deallocation Freezing my thread

Tags: haskell, freeglut

I have a forkOS thread which is the only thread talking to freeGlut.  Everything goes fine.  The thread polls for thunks to compute, and does them just happily.  But when I go to kill it with an exit statement it freezes and leaves child windows dangling on my desktop (note: that this is in the threads code; where I'm trying to deallocate glut cleanly; not a thunk it's taking in).  Has anybody ran into this issue, or knows what would cause it?

```
g i o = do
        m <- tryReadSig i
        case m of
            Just (GlutKill)     -> do
                                   putStrLn "exiting"
                                   Glut.exit
                                   putStrLn "exited"
                                   writeSigF o ()
```

This is really what it all boils down to.  The console puts out exiting then hangs.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add a minimal full example?